# How could I write this function in ES6/ES7?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get some information on how to improve this function in Javascript using ES6/ES7

```
function inclusive(min, max, input) {
  var difference = function(a, b) {
    return Math.abs(max - min)
  };
  return Array.apply(0, Array(difference() + 1))
    .map(function(element, index) {
      var integer = index + min;
      if (input.indexOf(integer) === -1) {
        return integer;
      }
    }).filter(function(n) {
      return typeof n !== 'undefined'
    });
}
```

Comment: Please explain what "this function" does, and make that the title of your question. See [ask].

Comment: you should be able to look at it and tell what it does, i'm simply looking for anyone's input on es6/es7 versions of the function

Comment: That's not the point. It's your job to *present* reviewers your code, tell us about it. And imagine the front page if every single question was "How could I improve this code?" - we have established community consensus on posting guidelines through the years for a reason.

Answer (score 2):

Your code obfuscates the goal, partially because of a generic non-telling function name.
And it needlessly scans the entire input array for each value in [min, max] range.

Basically, the goal is to list values in [min, max] range that aren't present in the input array:

```
let rangeExceptInput = (min, max, input) => {
    let range = new Array(max - min + 1).fill(0).map((e, index) => min + index);
    let inputInRange = new Set(input.filter(e => e >= min && e <= max));
    return range.filter(e => !inputInRange.has(e));
}
```

ES6 [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) is used to speed up the lookup of existing values.

This approach isn't super efficient though, so if JS profiler shows considerable time spent here, you can implement it differently, for example, by using a sorted inRange and plain for-loops.